# How to create asp.net web page with basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, basic-authentication

I want to create ASP.NET web page which will prompt me basic authentication popup where in I will enter credentials.
I tried adding below lines of code in PreInit and PreLoad event handlers but still it is not showing me basic authentication popup.

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreInit(e);
            Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
        }



protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreLoad(e);
    Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
    Response.AppendHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
}
```

Can you please help me with this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as the answers below note, you're better of doing this via IIS instead of trying to re-implement the same thing in your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically do this in IIS. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication

The short version:

- ensure that the basic authentication feature is enabled on your server
- disable anonymous authentication in your site and enable basic authentication

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. Marking it as answer. Can you tell me how to configure username and password and URL to be redirected after successful authentication ?

Comment: On the page that's secured by basic authentication, put a control or other mechanism to redirect to where you want the user to go to. You won't have their username / password, but if the target page is also secured with basic authentication to the same account, they will be able to access it.